# Android - Setting both TileMode and Gravity

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have a `ListView` in an XML-layout. I want to set a new background to this view by using the following code:

```
BitmapDrawable TileMe = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_skyline));
TileMe.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); // Bottom
TileMe.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
ListView test = getListView();
test.setBackgroundDrawable(TileMe);
```

The problem is that if I leave both the `Gravity` and the `TileMode` lines uncommented, only `TileMode` will work. If i comment the `TileMode` line, the `Gravity` line will work.

Am I doing something wrong or is Android messing with my head?

Answer (score 4):

Gravity is ignored when the tile mode is enabled. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

Comment: Is there a workaround?  This makes sense for 'full' tile mode, but not for x and y only.