# Android Background repeat Y and right aligned

Tags: android, background, tile, nine-patch, gravity

How do I tile the background image along the **right** side of my layout?

[image: Tile on Right Side]

*Attempt 1: XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/scroll_grip"
    android:tileModeY="repeat"
    android:gravity="right"/>  <!-- ignored -->
```

*Attempt 2: In code setting actual image*

```
  BitmapDrawable toTile = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scroll_grip));
  toTile.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
  toTile.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // ignored
  findViewById(R.id.scroll_grip_holder).setBackground(toTile);
```

*Attempt 3: In code calling XML*

Same as Attempt 2, but I included the xml drawable.  When I did this, no image was displayed.

*Attempt 4: nine-patch*

I also tried various attempts with 9-patch but there was no visible difference.

This question appears to repeat [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036447/) but the accepted solution does not work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674558/1229250 states that gravity is ignored when tile mode is activated